# Wireless Connectivity Issues on Some Networks - Acer Aspire 1410 - Solved

Tags: networking, internet

I have Freya installed on an Acer Aspire 1410 and I am having issues with the wireless connection on my home network.

The odd thing is, I have a perfect connection at my local coffee shop.

I had seen some articles talking about changing the MTU and that hasn't seemed to help me. The connection at my home will constantly disconnect or be very slow.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Running sudo lshw -C network brings up:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:1e:64:17:24:3e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-47-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:28 memory:92500000-92501fff
```

Edit 2: I followed the steps and did this

```
    rob@rob-Aspire-1410:~/Downloads$ tar -xvf iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz
iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/
iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/README.iwlwifi-1000-ucode
iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/LICENSE.iwlwifi-1000-ucode
rob@rob-Aspire-1410:~/Downloads$ sudo cp iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware 
[sudo] password for rob: 
rob@rob-Aspire-1410:~/Downloads$ sudo cp iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware 
rob@rob-Aspire-1410:~/Downloads$
```

Running the first command yields

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:1e:64:17:24:3e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-47-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.0.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:28 memory:92500000-92501fff
```

How do I know if I followed the steps correctly and it worked? I am currently on my home network and haven't had any drops yet so that is promising. P.S. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you execute "sudo lshw -C network" from terminal and share the output editing your question, in order to know your chipset wifi card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try updating the wifi driver with a newer version from [Wiki Kernel: iwlwifi](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi). To your N-1000 card and kernel 3.19 you must download the next file:

[iwlwifi 1000](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz)

After this, go to your  Downloads folder and open a terminal. Untar the file with:

```
tar -xvf iwlwifi-1000-*.tar.gz
```

Now you must copy the new firmware. Again from terminal:

```
sudo cp iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1/iwlwifi-1000-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

That wireless card should drop occasionally with 11n connection,  so execute from terminal :

```
 echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot the system and check your wireless connection.

Comment: Thank you again! I edited my question to include what I entered to double check that I did it correctly. My connection has been stable for about an hour so I am hesitantly optimistic. Thank you again!

Comment: Just had a drop so maybe I did not do it correctly :/

Comment: I edit my answer to add a tick to solve occasionally drops. Please share your report.

Comment: I have had a solid connection all morning so I think you did the trick. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome Rob. Please mark answer as useful to help others. Thanks